# Angular: ui-bootstrap dropdown triggers empty watch

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have an interesting issue where an angular-ui-bootstrap dropdown toggle directive closes itself when another dropdown directive is added to the page at runtime. Upon debugging, it looks like the close is firing because of the watch on $location.path saying results are not equal:

```
scope.$watch('$location.path', function() { closeMenu(); });
```

A few points of interest:

1) ui-bootstrap does not seem to $location.path as a scope variable in this directive (it is always undefined).

2) The last watch value on $location.path is always set to initWatchVal, even after subsequent watch triggers.

I realize this use case is a bit esoteric as it's not typical to insert directives at runtime, but any help on this is appreciated.

Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/2XyQZg9KFgFH9PTDCW8I?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

This `$watch` has already been replaced by watching for `$locationChangeSuccess`.

Comment: I can see that on master, but the latest published version (0.10) still has this.

Is there a timetable to release the updated version of this directive?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no timeline, but you could always build the latest file from master yourself.